# Subsequent offensive-deletion of post you voted to delete normally incorrectly attributes intent

Tags: discussion, bug, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete, offensive

This is a small bug but nonetheless.

There was an answer where I felt it was teetering on the edge of merely NAA and rude & abusive. I downvoted it and cast a delete vote. It was latter destroyed as abusive by a mod.

Now, when people visit that post, they see this:

[image]

The deletion text implies that **my** reason for voting to delete the answer was because I found it to be "spam or offensive". That's not true however. I merely voted to delete. Voting to delete does not allow you to select a reason for deletion, so the system has no way of knowing whether I actually found that or if I just thought it was NAA.

This is of course a minor bug but it can lead to user intent getting misassigned when it actually happens to controversial posts. And it provides a target for the backlash of users who have been affected by such an action, like:

> "Who is this Magisch guy and why does he delete my answers as
>   offensive?! I'll show em!"

That's presumably the reason it does not show the flagger names on normal destroyed posts, so it's weird to show the name of someone who didn't actually flag in such a way.

My proposed solution would be to just not list any delete voters besides Community when a post is destroyed before the delete votes take effect. The votes had no impact on the outcome of the post, so I'd say they don't need to be marked as such.

Comment: That's exactly how close votes work too. Among five different people, you can have multiple close-vote reasons. But only a single reason is given in the message box—and all names are listed under that reason.